# How to insert lots of data to notifications table with one query in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, push-notification, notifications

I want to insert some data to notifications table. I know I can do it with `ToArray()` in Channel Notification. But I want to do it faster. In `ToArray()` Method, Laravel sends query for each user and it's slow. I want to send all data to database with a query and Insert method doesn't exist for Notification. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

for batch inserts, you should use the query builder without eloquent model:

```
DB::table('notifications')->insert([
    [firstRowInfo],
    [secondRowInfo],
    ...
]);
```